# using FindRoot to solve 3 simultaneous equations

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to solve 3 simultaneous equations derived from an electrical circuit of a common source amplifier.

```
RS := 2200

RD := 4700

RE := 10000

RL := 10000

kN := 0.001

vDD := 10

vTN := 1

U[x_] = 0.5*(1 + Tanh[x/(10^-5)])

iD[vGS_, vDS_] = (1 - U[vTN - vGS])*(1 - U[vDS - (vGS - vTN)])*
   kN ((vGS - vTN)*vDS - (vDS^2)/2) + (1 - U[vTN - vGS])*
   U[vDS - (vGS - vTN)]*kN/2*(vGS - vTN)^2

vS := -2

FindRoot[{vDD + vS - vGS - iD[vGS_, vDS_]*RE == 0, 
  vDD + v0 - vDS - iD[vGS_, vDS_]*RE == 0, 
  vDD - v0*(1 + RD/RL) - RD*iD[vGS_, vDS_] == 0}, {{vGS, 10}, {vDS, 
   10}, {v0, 10}}]
```

I keep on getting this error:

> The function value {-2.`-10000.` (0.00025`(-1.`+Pattern[<<2>>])^2 \
>   (1.`-0.5` Plus[<<2>>]) (1.`+Tanh[Times[<<2>>]])+0.001` (-1.`\
>   Power[<<2>>]+Pattern[<<2>>] Plus[<<2>>]) (1.` -0.5`Plus[<<2>>]) (1.`
>   \
>   -0.5`Plus[<<2>>])),10.` -10000.`(0.00025` (-1.`+Pattern[<<2>>])^2 \ (1.` -0.5`Plus[<<2>>]) (1.` +Tanh[Times[<<2>>]])+0.001`(-1.` \
>   Power[<<2>>]+<<1>> <<1>>) <<1>> (1.`-0.5` \
>   Plus[<<2>>])),-4.699999999999999`-4700.` (0.00025`\
>   (-1.`+Pattern[<<2>>])^2 (1.`-0.5` Plus[<<2>>]) (1.`\
>   +Tanh[Times[<<2>>]])+0.001` (-1.`Power[<<2>>]+Pattern[<<2>>] \ Plus[<<2>>]) (1.` -0.5`Plus[<<2>>]) (1.` -0.5`Plus[<<2>>]))} is not
>   \ a list of numbers with dimensions {3} at {vGS,vDS,v0} = \
>   {10.`,10.`,10.`}. >>

please help? I have little experience with mathematica and its for a uni assignment.

Answer (score 2):

1) Use `SetDelayed` (:=) for function definition, `Set` (=) for constants.

2) Don't use a pattern (_) in evaluation of the function.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

RD = 4700

RE = 10000

RL = 10000

kN = 0.001

vDD = 10

vTN = 1

U[x_] := 0.5*(1 + Tanh[x/(10^-5)])

iD[vGS_, vDS_] := (1 - U[vTN - vGS]) (1 - 
     U[vDS - (vGS - vTN)]) kN ((vGS - vTN) vDS - (vDS^2)/2) + (1 - 
     U[vTN - vGS]) U[vDS - (vGS - vTN)] kN/2 (vGS - vTN)^2

vS = -2

FindRoot[{vDD + vS - vGS - iD[vGS, vDS]*RE == 0, 
  vDD + v0 - vDS - iD[vGS, vDS] RE == 0, 
  vDD - v0 (1 + RD/RL) - RD*iD[vGS, vDS] == 0}, {{vGS, 10}, {vDS, 
   10}, {v0, 10}}]

(* {vGS -> 2.08743, vDS -> 8.99974, v0 -> 4.91231} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: 1) is not generally true, but I'm sure you are aware of that.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Yes, was referring to OP use case...